# How do I access the dealloc method in a class category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, nstimer

I need to perform an action in the dealloc method of a category. I've tried swizzling but that doesn't work (nor is it a great idea).

In case anyone asks, the answer is no, I can't use a subclass, this is specifically for a category.

I want to perform an action on delay using `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]` or `[self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` and cancel it on dealloc.

The first issue is that `NSTimer` retains the target, which I don't want. `[self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` doesn't retain, but I need to be able to call `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]` in the `dealloc` method or we get a crash.

Any suggestions how to do this on a category?

Comment: Means ? Did your implementation file not contains the dealloc method ?

Comment: Seeing some code would be good, even if it does not work (or does not work yet).

Comment: You can use Matt Gallagher's ["supersequent implementation"](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html).  Be sure to consider the drawbacks of this approach in contrast to swizzling, though.

Comment: It sounds like you want to take some arbitrary action when an instance of a class whose implementation you don't have access to is deallocated. Swizzling `dealloc` should work, as long as you call the original method too; the category override won't because you can't access the original. If you elaborate on what the action you need to take is, somebody might be able to suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: Nate, I tried the supersequent implementation and that didn't work either. The moment I call the supersequent dealloc method the instance is freed and then instantly retained (by some ARC magic) and I get a crash. I'd rather not have to stop using ARC.

Comment: Your solution to your use case is unfortunately flawed: `dealloc` will not be called _because_ the timer retains the target.

Comment: nothing works for you ..... and only you. add some code or so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just stumbled on a solution to this that I haven't seen before, and seems to work...

I have a category that--as one often does--needs some state variables, so I use `objc_setAssociatedObject`, like this:

```
Memento *m = [[[Memento alloc] init] autorelease];
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kMementoTagKey, m, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

And, I needed to know when the instances my category extending were being `dealloc`ed. In my case it's because I set observers on `self`, and have to remove those observers at some point, otherwise I get the `NSKVODeallocateBreak` leak warnings, which could lead to bad stuff.

Suddenly it dawned on me, since my associated objects were being `retain`ed (because of using `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`), they must be being `release`d also, and therefore being `dealloc`ed...in fact I had implemented a `dealloc` method in the simple storage class I had created for storing my state values. And, I postulated: *my associated objects must be dealloced **before** my category's instances are!* So, I can have my associated objects notify their owners when they realize they are being `dealloc`ed! Since I already had my retained associated objects, I just had to add an `owner` property (which is *not* specified as `retain`!), set the owner, and then call some method on the owner in the associated object's `dealloc` method.

Here's a modified part of my category's .m file, with the relevant bits:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h> // So we can use objc_setAssociatedObject, etc.
#import "TargetClass+Category.h"

@interface TargetClass_CategoryMemento : NSObject
{
    GLfloat *_coef;
}
@property (nonatomic) GLfloat *coef;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id owner;
@end
@implementation TargetClass_CategoryMemento
-(id)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _coef = (GLfloat *)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * 15);
    }
    return self;
};
-(void)dealloc {
    free(_coef);
    if (_owner != nil 
        && [_owner respondsToSelector:@selector(associatedObjectReportsDealloc)]) {
        [_owner associatedObjectReportsDealloc];
    }
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

@implementation TargetClass (Category)

static NSString *kMementoTagKey = @"TargetClass+Category_MementoTagKey";

-(TargetClass_CategoryMemento *)TargetClass_CategoryGetMemento
{
    TargetClass_CategoryMemento *m = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kMementoTagKey);
    if (m) {
        return m;
    }
    // else
    m = [[[TargetClass_CategoryMemento alloc] init] autorelease];
    m.owner = self; // so we can let the owner know when we dealloc!
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kMementoTagKey, m,  OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    return m;
}

-(void) doStuff
{
    CCSprite_BlurableMemento *m = [self CCSprite_BlurableGetMemento];
    // do stuff you needed a category for, and store state values in m
}

-(void) associatedObjectReportsDealloc
{
    NSLog(@"My associated object is being dealloced!");
    // do stuff you need to do when your category instances are dealloced!
}

@end
```

The pattern here I learned somewhere (probably on S.O.) uses a factory method to get or create a memento object. Now it sets the owner on the memento, and the memento's `dealloc` method calls back to let the owner know it's being `dealloc`ed

CAVEATS:

- Obviously, you have to have your associated object set with `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`, or it won't be retained and released for you automatically.
- This becomes trickier if your memento/state associated object gets `dealloc`ed under other circumstances than the owner being `dealloc`ed...but you can probably train one object or the other to ignore that event.
- The `owner` property can't be declared as `retain`, or you'll truly create a strong reference loop and neither object will ever qualify to be `dealloc`ed!
- I don't know that it's documented that `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` associated objects are necessarily `release`d before the owner is completely `dealloc`ed, but it seems to happen that way and almost must be the case, intuitively at least.
- I don't know if `associatedObjectReportsDealloc` will be called *before* or *after* the `TargetClass`'s dealloc method--*this could be important!* If it runs afterwards, if you try to access member objects of the `TargetClass` you will crash! And my guess is that it's afterwards.

This is a little messy, because you're double-linking your objects, which requires you to be very careful to keep those references straight. But, it doesn't involve swizzling, or other interference with the runtime--this just relies on a certain behavior of the runtime. Seems like a handy solution if you already have an associated object. In some cases it might be worth creating one just to catch your own `dealloc`s!

Comment: Such a clever way around this! This is a brilliant hack that allows objc categories to become so much more powerful. Thanks for sharing! Others are recommending subclassing, and typically I would agree, however some classes are just not good candidates for subclassing (Class clusters... I'm looking your direction).

Answer (score 8):

*I still think it would be better to subclass your class and not mess with the runtime, but if you are definitely sure you need to do it in a category, I have an option in mind for you. It still messes with the runtime, but is safer than swizzling I think.*

Consider writing a helper class, say calling it `DeallocHook` which can be attached to any `NSObject` and perform an action when this `NSObject` gets deallocated. Then you can do something like this:

```
// Instead of directly messing with your class -dealloc method, attach
// the hook to your instance and do the cleanup in the callback 
[DeallocHook attachTo: yourObject 
             callback: ^{ [NSObject cancelPrevious... /* your code here */ ]; }];
```

You can implement the `DeallocHook` using `objc_setAssociatedObject`:

```
@interface DeallocHook : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) dispatch_block_t callback;

+ (id) attachTo: (id) target callback: (dispatch_block_t) block;

@end
```

Implementation would be something like this:

```
#import "DeallocHook.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

// Address of a static global var can be used as a key
static void *kDeallocHookAssociation = &kDeallocHookAssociation;

@implementation DeallocHook

+ (id) attachTo: (id) target callback: (dispatch_block_t) block
{
    DeallocHook *hook = [[DeallocHook alloc] initWithCallback: block];

    // The trick is that associations are released when your target
    // object gets deallocated, so our DeallocHook object will get
    // deallocated right after your object
    objc_setAssociatedObject(target, kDeallocHookAssociation, hook, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    return hook;
}


- (id) initWithCallback: (dispatch_block_t) block
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        // Here we just copy the callback for later
        self.callback = block;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) dealloc
{
    // And we place our callback within the -dealloc method
    // of your helper class.
    if (self.callback != nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), self.callback);
}

@end
```

See Apple's documentation on [Objective-C runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for more info about the associative references (although I'd say the docs are not very detailed regarding this subject).

I've not tested this thoroughly, but it seemed to work. Just thought I'd give you another direction to look into.

Comment: How does this inform the class to call the block on call to `dealloc`?

Comment: he did write it above: The trick is that associations are released when your target object gets deallocated, so our DeallocHook object will get deallocated right after your object

Comment: Associations are automatically released when your object gets deleted, so if no other references to the hook object remain, it will be deallocated as well. The block is called in `-dealloc` of the hook object and that does the trick. It's just an idea and might not work in your case since I'm not sure in what order the `-dealloc` methods would get called on your object and on the hook object, but the whole scheme seems worth a try.

Comment: Clever idea! Something to commit to memory, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution unfortunately won't work: *because* `NSTimer` retains its target, the target will never run its `dealloc` until the timer has been invalidated. The target's retain count will always be hovering at 1 or above, waiting for the timer to release it. You have to get to the timer *before* `dealloc`. (Pre-ARC, you *could* override `retain` and `release` and destroy the timer, although that's really not a good solution.)

[`NSThread` also has this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032660/603977), and the solution is simple: a bit of redesigning separates the controller of the thread from the "model". The object which creates and owns the thread, or timer in this case, should not also be the target of the timer. Then, instead of the retain cycle you currently have (timer owns object which owns timer), you have a nice straight line: controller owns timer which owns target. Outside objects only need to interact with the controller: when it is deallocated, it can shut down the timer without you having to play games with overriding `dealloc` or other memory management methods.

That's the best way to handle this. In the case that you can't do that for some reason -- you're talking about category overrides, so apparently you don't have the code for the class which is the target of the timer (but you can still probably make a controller even in that case) -- you can use weak references. Unfortunately I don't know any way to make an `NSTimer` take a weak reference to its target, but GCD will give you a fair approximation via `dispatch_after()`. Get a weak reference to the target and use that exclusively in the Block you pass. The Block will not retain the object through the weak reference (the way `NSTimer` would), and the weak reference will of course be `nil` if the object has been deallocated before the Block runs, so you can safely write whatever message sends you like.

Comment: I like this idea. I like it a lot. I'll have to give it a try.